# Soundcloud API works on Firefox but not on Safari or Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundcloud

http://jsfiddle.net/gwz3rchj/76/

I am using this piece of code. No errors in the console. It's not loading the sound at all.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    SC.initialize({
    client_id: "43e02302fc33adb2051f2391815f1828"

  });

 $("#stream").on("click", function(){
    SC.stream("/tracks/293", {autoPlay: true});
  });


});
```

Comment: Where have you tested this, to be clear?  Just jsfiddle?

Comment: I've tested this on Yosemite. Multiple browsers and only Firefox works. If you see the network tab the soundmanager javascript library is being loaded in chrome and safari but not the swf or the rest of the audio file.

Comment: Ya, I've been able to reproduce, and when adding a callback to the stream method, it returns false, but I haven't yet been able to figure out why.

Comment: The API itself works. Looks like they have an issue with the JS-SDK only - SC.stream method or the underlying sm2. Dont know while it stuck right after loading the SM2. When you look at the date, its wrong compared with the latest sm2-version. Versioncode is correct.

Comment: Yes, the API does work but it's something with the SM2 on Chrome and Safari. I think you already reproduced the issue. I hope SoundCloud attend to this problem. For now, I'll use an alternative method to play the tunes.

Comment: Try again, looks like some magic happened. Dont know what was changed.

Comment: Tried, doesn't work. On chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/gwz3rchj/76/ gives no sound. As usual as before. Does still work on FF and Safari though. Is it working for you? No way? How?

Comment: Ok, i works for me on Chrome 38.0.2115.102, Android 4.4.4, V8 3.28.71.15 - but not on my desktop. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I reproduce this on Chrome 47 OSX (track id 63498561), working on Safari and FF.

Answer (score 1):

Its jsfiddle issue , I think becuase it is using `IFrame`

[here is working sample on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2dIBWIa188GDLENmVfbl?p=preview)

Comment: Why should iFrame use change anything?

Comment: try to open http://fiddle.jshell.net/gwz3rchj/76/show/light/ and make sure its iframeless it will work, the issue in fiddle not the browser

Comment: Any idea as to why that should be the case?